# how to write random numbers to file in python

Tags: python, list, file

I would like to store 100 randomly drawn numbers in a file.
How can I write random numbers to a list, using a file?
How can I read a file?
How can I separate draw numbers

```
import random
draw = [] 

while True:
    numbers_lotto = random.randint(1,50)    
    draw.append(numbers_lotto)
    if len(draw) == 5 # the numbers?
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

file_name = 'random_numbers.txt'

with open ('file_name', 'w') as a_file:
    for i in range (100):
        a_file.write ('{}\n'.format (random.random ()))

with open ('file_name', 'r') as a_file:
    a_list = [float (word) for word in a_file.read () .split ()]

print (a_list)
```

or

```
import random
import pickle

file_name = 'random_numbers.txt'

with open (file_name, 'wb') as a_file:
    pickle.dump ([random.random () for i in range (100)], a_file)

with open (file_name, 'rb') as a_file:
    a_list = pickle.load (a_file)

print (a_list)
```